# n samples all sampled from N(mu,1), the sampling process is NOT i.i.d, how to estimate mu?

Tags: statistics, regression, correlation

$n$ samples $X_{i}$ for $0\leq i<n$ are sampled from a $N(\mu, 1)$ , however, the sampling process is NOT i.i.d, there is a correlation among sampling process, the correlation matrix is $C$, where all the off diagonal elements are $r$.

Given these $n$ samples, how can I estimate $\mu$? How to estimate the confidence interval of this estimate ?

If there is no correlation, i.e., the samples are all iid, then the estimate should be easier:

$E(\mu) = \sum(X_{i})/n$

My guess is that , this problem has some connection with linear regression:

given a vector $m=[\mu, \mu, \mu ...]$ of size $n$, and a vector $x=[X_{0}, X_{1}, ... X_{n}]$

$ m = C*x$

Not sure if this is correct though, can anyone share some thoughts?

Comment: Do you have any particular estimation method in mind? Is the common correlation a known quantity?

Comment: If the sampling is unbiased though correlated then $\sum(X_{i})/n$ is still an unbiased estimator of the population mean, but the standard error of the sample mean will be larger than if the sampling was independent